# What am i missing for the file upload using multipart form data ?

Tags: node.js

Hi for whatever reason i cannot use packages e.g. multer to upload file to node server. So i found example online, if just upload file in the form, it works fine.
Now i want to send another field "password" together with the file during submit, just cannot make it a work.

I do know there're plenty modules out there, for now just want to this example to work.

```
<form style="height: 100%;padding-bottom:63px;">
    <p>
        <input type="file" class="FirmwareFile"
               name="myUpload" file-model="upload.newFwFile">
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
               placeholder="Password" 
               ng-model="upload.controllerPassword"
               class="formInput">
    </p>
</form>

httpSvc.uploadToUrl(myFile, myPd, myServerIPAddress, myRoute) {...}

factory.uploadToUrl = function (fwFile, pd, myServerIp, myRoute) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    //fd.append('passwd', pd); // cannot pass password to server side ?
    fd.append('file', fwFile); // only this works

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var completeUrl = ......

    $http.post(completeUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function () {
        deferred.reject();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

in server side, where to extract the password info please ?

```
var UploadImage = function(req, res, callback){
    var destFile = fs.createWriteStream(uploadDest + "mytest");
    var fileSize = req.headers['content-length'];
    req.pipe(destFile); //why not sth. like req.body.file.pipe() ?
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form does not have

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="..." method="..."> 
  ... 
</form>
```

You will be better off using [node-formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable). The example works straight out of the box. You might also want to look into angularJS specific form upload directives that have been made. No sense in reinventing the wheel.

Cheers